# Metodos strings - isdigit e isdecimal

Tags: python

O método `'str'.isdigit()` vai sempre retorna o mesmo T/F que isdecimal() ou existe alguma diferença no algoritmo destes métodos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É principalmente sobre classificações unicode. Veja alguns exemplos para mostrar discrepâncias:

```
>>> def spam(s):
...     for attr in 'isnumeric', 'isdecimal', 'isdigit':
...         print(attr, getattr(s, attr)())
...         
>>> spam('½')
isnumeric True
isdecimal False
isdigit False
>>> spam('³')
isnumeric True
isdecimal False
isdigit True
```

Confira a resposta completa aqui https://stackoverflow.com/a/44891216/4007642